# How to Insert/Update tables using sql view in EF?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a sql view which joins a few tables in my db. I am loading the sql view in EF and I am trying to insert and update data using the sql view. I have triggers in my db to tell the view how to insert and update the correct tables.

Is this possible using EF MVC ?

Comment: yes you can use `ExecuteSqlCommand`, please refer to this link for more info http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: Hi @ElyasEsna, thanks you for your suggestion. I was able to find a much simpler way of doing the above. I made use of stored procedures, and I just called the stored procedure in my web api method.